# Why does BlueJeans sometime fail to show the screenshare and instead display a grey window?

Tags: windows, screen-sharing, bluejeans

Why does BlueJeans sometime fail to show the screenshare and instead display a grey window?

In the screenshot below, a participant is sharing their screen but on my computer I see a dark screen instead (whereas I do see the participant's screen share when using BlueJeans on my iPad):

[image]

I use BlueJeans 2.18.39.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Everything works fine on the iPad, aside from being low definition:

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted bluejeans support?

Comment: @Moab yes, waiting for the reply.